# Why does calling HEAD on this URL prevent the following error: ERROR: Message: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

Tags: windows, ssl, curl, clamav

This is an issue I'm having with a specific package but it looks like the software is using a version of CURL for windows or something. I want to understand this specific behavior because it doesnt make sense to me.

Im using this software which is a custom distro of clamav for windows: https://oss.netfarm.it/clamav/

Specifically this version: https://oss.netfarm.it/clamav/files/clamav-x64-0.102.1.7z

I call an exe in that package: `& 'c:\clamav\freshclam.exe'`
And I get the following error:

```
Trying again in 5 secs...
daily database available for download (remote version: 25759)
ERROR: Download failed (60) ERROR:  Message: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
ERROR: getcvd: Can't download daily.cvd from https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
Giving up on https://database.clamav.net...
ERROR: Update failed for database: daily
WARNING: fc_update_databases: fc_update_database failed: Connection failed (5)
ERROR: Database update process failed: Connection failed (5)
ERROR: Update failed.
```

Dont get it because I can access that URL without issue. I then found if I run HEAD against that URL first before running the exe it works:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd' -Method HEAD
# Now this will work
& 'c:\clamav\freshclam.exe'
```

I think they might have implemented curl libs wrong or something? I dont understand what could even cause this. Does invoke-webquest fetch and cache certs but curl (or the apps use of it) does not do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the SSL certificates:

```
apt install ca-certificates
update-ca-certificates
```

Comment: this is windows

Comment: Uhh, you're right! Are there still people using windows these days?!?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i'am! I have 8 installs where clamav is working like a charm and one throwing this message:SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).